# Debugging GScript called by Google App

Tags: google-apps-script

I have written some GScript that is called by a Google App (Awesome Tables).

How do I debug the GScript while it is running after being initiated by the Google App (I particularly want to see that values in variables as I step through the code)?

Answer (score 1):

I found that Google Apps Script has a Logger Class. I used this to log messages when certain stages in my code was reached (some included variable values) and then emailed the whole log to myself. See https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/base/logger

Answer (score 0):

I don't know of a way to do this. The best approach is probably to mimic the calling application by creating a test function in your Google Apps Script that calls the main function with the appropriate parameters. Then you can step through the code and see values using the debugger.

Answer (score 0):

Try to check this [Debugging](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/troubleshooting#debugging) part in the Google Apps Script documentation if it can help you.

It is stated here that there are some strategies for handling errors and investigating a script that is not running the way you expect.

- [Execution transcript](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/troubleshooting#execution_transcript)
- [Logging custom messages](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/troubleshooting#logging_custom_messages)
- [Using the debugger and breakpoints](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/troubleshooting#using_the_debugger_and_breakpoints)

For more information, check this [Some Simple Debugging for Google Apps Script](http://www.mousewhisperer.co.uk/drivebunny/some-simple-debugging-for-google-apps-script/)